# WPF and C# - Create x:static binding in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, delegates

Even if similar questions are already posted, I still haven't found a solution.
In XAML I have this kind of "binding" that works good:

```
<Controls:MyCustomControl MyCustomAction="{x:Static staticTest:TestDelegate.myConverterAction}" [...]>
```

Now, I need to set the `MyCustomAction` property (that is a delegate property) in this way but via code.
Is there a way to make a `x:Static` bind in XAML using C#?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of you XAML in C# code would simply be:

```
MyCustomControl mcc = ...;

mcc.MyCustomAction = TestDelegate.myConverterAction;
```

Comment: Yes, of course...but when I set the property in this way via a ModelItem object in XAML I only see the ToString() return value: MyCustomAction="myConverterAction" ...